# Filter out errors/warnings by project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, filter

Is there a way to filter errors/warnings by project in Visual Studio 2010?

For example, if project A has dependencies for project B and C, Visual Studio will show errors/warnings for both project A, B and C, even whenever I compile project A alone.

I don't mind if VS show A's errors/warnings when I compile the entire solution, but I would like VS to show only A's errors/warnings whenever I compile it alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can completely filter the errors and warnings of a particular project out, especially not if there are dependencies that are failing.  You can't know about problems in A if it depends on B and B is not building.

In the errors list pane (View > Error List), the last column is "Project", and you can click the column header to sort your errors.  The sorting should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it is not strictly relevant to VS2010 but since VS2012 it has been possible to filter the Error List by Open Documents Current Project or Current Document.

[See this blog for more information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2012/04/13/visual-studio-2011-filter-the-error-list.aspx).